# Angular form design, should i use multiple forms or it's better to use a single form?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-forms

I am going to implement a modal of configuration settings, the UI looks like the attached image[image]

Multiple tabs on the sidebar, the content of each tab will be a form in the right panel.

API will fetch all the settings config once when the modal is open.

There's no API for fetching data of each individual tab, and all data will be saved after pressing the 'Save' button of the modal.

API data response:

```
config: {
    network: {...},
    proxy: {...}
    ...
    download: {...}
}
```

**Question:**

**How should I design the data management of this scenario?**

- `formValues.subscribe` on each detail form, and emit the event to parent modal component for syncing data?
- Should I consider using NgRx? I don't really have experience with it. Is it a good scenario I should use NgRx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if **is your "parent"** who create the whole form

```
form=new FormGroup({
   network:new FormGroup({
     prop1:new FormControl(settingsService.network.prop1),
     prop2:new FormControl(settingsService.network.prop2),
   }),
   proxy:new FormGroup({
     prop1:new FormControl(settingsService.proxy.prop1),
     prop2:new FormControl(settingsService.proxy.prop2),
   })
   ...
})
```

You can pass the formGroup to your "children"

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <config-component *ngIf="step==0" [group]="form.get('config')"></config-component>
   <proxy-component *ngIf="step==1" [group]="form.get('proxi')"></proxi-component>
    ...
</form>
```

Your childrens like

```
@Input() group;

<form [formGroup]="group">
   <input formControlName="prop1">
   <input formControlName="prop2">
</form>
```

You don't loose the values of the form because you has it always in "parent"

**Update**. Complementary my comments using a service

Imagine you has a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {

  data:any={}
  constructor() { }

  getData():Observable<any>{
     ...we get the data from a http or localStore or...
     ...and use pipe(tap) to store the value in "data"
     e.g.
     return of({}).pipe(tap((res)=>this.data=res));
  }
  saveData(){
     ..we use this.data to post to an http or to save in localStore...
  }
}
```

Ours children are like

```
    export class OneComponent implements OnInit  {
      form:FormGroup  
    
      constructor(private dataService:DataService){}
      ngOnInit()
      {
         //see that create the form using the data from this.dataService.data.config
         //in another component you'll use, e.g. this.dataService.data.netWork

        const data=this.dataService.data.config|| {prop1:null,prop2:null}
        this.form=new FormGroup(
          {
            prop1:new FormControl(data.prop1,Validators.required),
            prop2:new FormControl(data.prop2)
          })
      }
      saveData() //simple store in this.dataService.datadata.config the value of the form
                 //in another component you store, e.g. in this.dataService.datadata.netWork
      {
        this.dataService.data.config=this.form.value;
      }
    
    }
```

Our parent like

```
<button (click)="navigate(0)">Config</button>
<button (click)="navigate(1)">NetWork</button>
<one-component #component *ngIf="page==0">
</one-component>
<two-component #component *ngIf="page==1">
</two-component>
```

See the "reference variable", we use ViewChild to get the component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  @ViewChild('component') component:any;

  constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
  page=0;
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe()
  }
  isValid(){
    const form=this.component.form as FormGroup
    if (form.valid)
         this.component.saveData()
    else
      form.markAllAsTouched();

    return form.valid

  }
  navigate(newIndex:number)
  {
    if (this.isValid())
        this.page=newIndex
  }
  saveData()
  {
     if (this.isValid())
         this.dataService.saveData()
  }
}
```

You can see in [an ugly stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-erdosp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Should i use *ngIf or hidden for the sub component? If i use *ngIf, when re-enter the tab, the ngOnInit logic will be re-exectued again? Actually it is not a stepper form. I think i should build the children formGroup in children components, right?

Comment: using *ngIf, makes that if true Angular execute the ngOnInit. If the data is in parent and you feed the formGroup in the parent you can use *ngIf or hidden. If you feed the formGroup in the components (as j4rey's answer) you need use hidden. If you use "routes", you need a service that store the data -a service with public variables- (use the ngOnDestroy of each component to change the variables of the service) and you use ngOnInit to create the formControl based in the stored variables

Comment: Do you also think i should use a single form, instead of multiple separate forms? Actually there are more tabs then what i have posted. More than ten tabs in real situation. Putting all the logic inside the parent component will make the parent component bloated. WDYT?

Comment: Really, thinking about your question, I'm thinking that use a service to store the data and create components that create the formGroup can be a good idea. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes "There are many ways to skin a cat", the same applies here. Angular gives you the tools and leaves the architecture to you.

The multiple tabs on sidebar means you would probably go with master-detail layout.

And you could do the multiple form and as you already noticed means you would have to sync it up.

However, I would suggest using one form, which would wrap over the whole detail layout, and you would pass the form instance to the detail components.

So the idea is you will have a `FormGroup` in you parent component, so is the `Save` button. And you basically initialize it with empty `FormGroup`.

```
form = fb.group({});
```

which you then passing down to your detail view component as an `@Input` parameter and on the `ngOnInit()` you would add the `FormControl`

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.addControl('enableLogging', new FormControl(this.settingsService.config.enableLogging));
    // other form controls
}
```

The `settingsService.config` is your source-of-truth, i.e, the config returned from your api response.

Having a single form would give you two advantage:

1. You wouldn't have to mess with syncing up the data of each form, and consolidating it.
2. Since you have the single save button, which would save all the data, instead of having save on each tabs, having a single form, in the parent component, means you can simply post it with `this.form.value` on the click of save button.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds better than what i thought of.

Comment: a question regarding the single form. I should use hidden instead of *ngIf for displaying the detail when do the switch tab things, right? Because if i use *ngIf, re-enter the detail component will re-init the content, and previous data won't be persisted.

Comment: `ngIf` would probably give a problem, as it would destroy the component when you switch tab, and re-create the component when you re-visit the tab, which will call the `ngOnInit` -> `addControl` again. In this case, `style=display:none` would probably be a better option. If you want to go with `ngIf`, you would have to declare the formcontrols on the parent tab, and the detail tab would be `patch`-ing value instead of `addControl. Either way should be just fine.